# Eclipse Swing WindowBuilder returns error when trying to set border

Tags: eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I'm encountering a problem with Eclipse's Swing WindowBuilder.

When I click on the border options button to edit the border of the jPanel:

[image: source of the error - clicking on the border button]

I get the following error:

[image: problem -]

I am running on Mac OS X 10.8.4. With the following Eclipse version, and WindowBuilder version.

[image: eclipse version]

[image: window builder version]

Answer (score 0):

WindowBuilder has many, many, many problems. It looks like you've found one of them.
I had no problems trying to set the border using the same method as you, even though I am using the same version of eclipse as you.

***Workaround:***

To add a border, try switching to the code view and changing:
    `contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));`

To:
    `JBorder myBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black); 
    contentPane.setBorder(myBorder);`

Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html for more information on creating borders.