# Cannot select Factory for JLabel

Tags: java, border, jlabel

I added a JLabel to my JPanel and tried to select the BorderFactory so I can add a border. When I select the emptyBorder option, I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder cannot be cast to java.awt.Component
```

Isn't a JLabel part of Swing? How can I fix it so I can add a border to my JLabel easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
```

Comment: How can I do it without going into Source though?

Comment: @LoganKulinski if you're using a GUI builder, you're going to have to provide information as to what tool you're using.

Comment: I'm using WindowBuilder in Eclipse Mars.1. Sorry, thought I mentioned that.

Comment: In that case, you appear to be having the same problem as the asker of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594116/eclipse-swing-windowbuilder-returns-error-when-trying-to-set-border

Comment: Is there a better GUI Builder that you can recommend?

Comment: The best ones I've heard about are NetBeans and Google's [WindowBuilder](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Findex.html). Although I have become so familiar with hand-coding GUIs that is almost exclusively how I make them. I would highly recommend becoming very familiar with how Swing works from a code point of view.